# Hyper-V Server 2016 Version Upgrade

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server, hypervisor

Currently my Hyper-V 2016 host is running 1607 i've tried windows update a few times and I can't seem to get the system to update to newer builder versions or even previous like 1803,1809 etc..
if there a command or a download?

Here is my current system.

## Build version

Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId
ReleaseId    REG_SZ    1607

## get os build

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
10     0      14393  0

Comment: I don't believe Windows Server will ever use Windows Update to perform an upgrade like that - I think the only way to upgrade is by booting from the ISO and doing an in-place upgrade that way. Of course I never recommend in-place upgrades and I think clean-installs are the best approach.

Comment: If you want to install a newer build of Hyper-V you will need to use the ISO.  Feature Updates are installed over Windows Update on products like Hyper-V Server.  You obviously will need a license to the newer product if you do this.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't support this with Hyper-V server. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Server-Insiders/Microsoft-Hyper-V-Server-2019-is-live-on-the-Microsoft/td-p/693978  But, it's been reported it can be done.  Make sure you have valid backups of all your VMs before you try.  Ideally, you should build a new server and import the VMs into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 1903 is a semi-annual channel release that is a core only install.

There is no method to in-place upgrade 2016 (v1607) to Windows Server 1903
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/whats-new-in-windows-server-1903

Windows Server 2019 is a long term servicing branch release 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/whats-new-19

Windows Server 1903 would need to be clean installed, there isn't a method to switch between long term and semi-annual.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/servicing-channels-19

Links here as to where you can download Server 1903
https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/windowsserver/2019/05/21/windows-server-version-1903-now-generally-available/

Windows Server 2016 (v1607) updates are listed here 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825/windows-10-windows-server-2016-update-history
and can be downloaded here.
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com

Server 1809 and Server 1903 are technically "Server 2019"

Comment: Windows Server 2016 can be upgraded to Windows Server 2019.  As you correctly point out, Windows Server 2016 cannot be upgraded to Windows Server version 1903 due to the fact they are two entirely different editions.

Comment: There is a difference between `Windows Server 2019` and `Windows Server version 1903`.   They are not "technically" both Windows Server 2019.

Comment: I'd suggest you can read through the documentation here. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/whats-new-in-windows-server-1903 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/whats-new-in-windows-server-1903

Comment: All I see is two individual separate products one called Windows Server 2019 (LTSC) and the other Windows Server version 1903.

Comment: The OP's question is about Hyper-V server, not Windows Server.  Windows Server 2019 is a completely different product from Windows Server 1903.  You can, and I have, upgraded from Windows Server 2016 to Windows Server 2019.  Windows Server 2019 has an option for core or GUI installs also.  I believe the current version of Windows Server 2019 available is 1809 from March 2019.

Comment: life as an admin, over work, under appreciated... so yes @essjae is on the money. I thought , and please excuse my ignorance, 1903 was just an update sort of like Windows 10 1607=>1703=>1709=>1803=>1807=>1903 etc... or like SP (Service Pack) updates.

So am I to understand that I would have to reinstall an entire OS?

Comment: just an FYI: Hyper-V Server 2019 is build 1809